# How can I configurate CMakeLists.txt on CLion when startup?

Tags: c, cmake, clion

I use Clion. When i create new project, this files are being created:

- **CMakeLists.txt**
- **main.cpp**

But i wanna **main.c** file. Every new project i have to create manualy. I dont know cmake usage. Anyone help, how set the startup files, variables and conditions?

For example, i will guess clearly:

- In the generated CMakeLists.txt contain this:

  ```
  cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
  project(test)

  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

  set(SOURCE_FILES "main.cpp")
  add_executable(test ${SOURCE_FILES})
  ```
- but i wanna like this when startup:

  ```
  cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
  project(test)

  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

  set(SOURCE_FILES "main.c")
  add_executable(test ${SOURCE_FILES})
  ```

**And like this i want add another initial conditions. How can edit this?**

Comment: Google sez: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/2016.1/creating-and-editing-file-templates.html Or you could just edit the CMake file...

Comment: @CodyGray What I think the OP mean is that the OP would like to have different project templates to select from, so the OP could pick a "C project" and have a `main.c` file and correct `CMakeLists.txt` automatically generated from the start. I guess... And for the OP: It's really not a lot of work to edit the `CMakeLists.txt` and create a `main.c` file when you create the project. That would be the simplest part of any project I would say.

Comment: edited @Cody Gray,

Comment: Your question is unrelated to CMake. At least I cannot see a problem with CMake at all. Please drop the according tag.

Comment: Configrations may be making from cmake commands on terminal. So i add cmake tag,

Answer (score 0):

C project template is not yet supported. Should be added when this is implemented: [CPP-860](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-860)